# Are we travelling at a speed close to the light speed?

Tags: cosmology, speed-of-light, universe, space-expansion

This is a question which has been puzzling me quite a while.

There was a news report saying that the farthest galaxy spotted so far is at 13.3 billion light-years away, and it is said that the galaxy can show us how the universe at about 500 million years old was looked like.

It is commonly accepted that the universe was started from a single point some 13.8 billion years ago, and continuously expanding since then. Therefore, the new discovered farthest known galaxy should be much closer to us, or, at least to the materials forming our galaxy, at 13.3 billion years ago.

It implies, if the universe has been expanding in a constant speed, then we must be traveling away from the farthest known galaxy at 13.3/13.8, or 96%, of the light speed!

If the universe's expanding speed is not constant (it is said that the universe's expanding is accelerating due to the dark energy), then we must traveling away from the farthest known galaxy at an even greater speed.

But we know, it is not possible.

So, what is wrong here? Is my calculation (96% c) wrong, or the assertion of that the farthest known galaxy reflecting the universe in 13.3 billion years ago wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is the observable universe so big?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/26549/)