# Big Bang Physics/Cosmology

Tags: quantum-field-theory, cosmological-inflation, holographic-principle

Anyone care trying to explain how there is supposedly no center to the universe? Quantum Holography implies a center.  Any flowery language of proto atoms or cosmic eggs does as well too.  Even water droplet-like fission computer simulations of inflation can mathematically assign a center point.  Plainly speaking, QFT  hold spherical symmetry as well. And even our everyday common intuition lets us know things inflate symmetrically.  What gives?

Comment: The only (perhaps outdated) explanation I've ever encountered which I could wrap my head around is that the 3 spatial dimensions of our universe are analogous to the 2 dimensions on the surface of a sphere. The sphere surface has finite size, but has no boundaries or center; at any point on the surface, there are two orthogonal dimensions (linear degrees of freedom), despite the fact that apparently "linear" paths are actually curved, and following any "straight" path along the surface will eventually bring you back to your starting point. If there "is" a center, it "was" at the big bang(?)

Comment: Spherical symmetry just means that the laws of physics do not distinguish one direction in space over any other. But there is also translational symmetry: no point in space is distinguished over any other. Either every point is the center, or no point is.

Comment: Hmmm sounds a lot like S. Hawking's north pole global time analogy he later got blasted for.  What's wrong with thinking of colliding Branes or even perhaps a gigantic quantum fluctuation brought about by dark energy freezing, ripping, or diluting everything so this extremely "ordered" high  value entropy state mimics exactly a low value Initial Conditions state? the fluctuation could have been one thousandth the size of our visible universe or even one thousand times bigger than our visible universe...

Comment: Basically david h did a good job explaining gauge invariance but you could also think of gravitational bodies and radiating bodies losing "field" strength as the inverse relation of their formulae suggest (square of distance)

Answer (score 2):

The sphere analogy was given in the comments and is the simplest [visual example.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Bang)

[image: bb]

This is a small surface element on a two dimensional sphere in a three dimensional world where time is the third axis.

Seems to me you are glossing over time. Of course there exists a center in our four dimensional world where time is the fourth dimension. At t=0 the other coordinates are also zero and start growing. That is why it is called a bang.

There is no center on the surface of the four dimensional sphere of which we exist in the three space dimensional surface.

Comment: Although _bang_ is a misnomer, because there was nothing to expand into - spacetime just stretched out of the singularity

Comment: @dj_mummy 2-spheres get across the idea of centerless-ness (because for some reason people don't grasp that infinite planes can't have a center), but then they introduce curvature and moreover closure to the universe, which doesn't really reflect *our* universe. Alas, what can one do?