# If nothing can travel faster than speed of light then how the Universe is only 13.7 billion years old?

Tags: cosmology, universe, space-expansion, big-bang, faster-than-light

The light would take 93 billion years to reach the edge of universe but nothing can travel faster than the speed of light not even the big bang?

Comment: The big bang is a moment in time. NOT a point in space nor something that could travel

Comment: Space can expand faster than speed of light, the light we see from supposedly cosmic horizon had been left so back in time that it has been possible for it to reach us (remember it was all at one point at one time).

Comment: @rijulgupta saying it was all one point is misleading. There may have been no proper distance between places, but everything was still spatially separated. Sort of like a sphere with zero radius. No distance between points, but they're at different angular coordinates, so not the same points

Comment: @Jim : I would rather not discuss the singularity of big bang or the time of which even scientists just hypothesize, I have read many theories one of which have claims that everything was one dense point sometime, another says it all expanded from a large sphere or some other shape which makes it look like exploded from a point and some even say that we are inside a black hole. It's best to leave it alone for now!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/26549/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 1):

The big bang happened everywhere, simultaneously.  It wasn't an explosion happening in one place.  Everything is expanding away from everything else.

Comment: That does not answer the question! Please explain to OP why we can see a cosmic horizon so old in time that it should not have been possible to see!

Comment: @rijulgupta because the universe was smaller then - it does perfectly answer the question

Comment: To those who know about it already it is very evident from just saying that things were condense and close at one point,  I intended to say that the answer is not good enough for someone who has no such knowledge and the answer should explain how things were close when they released light and then got far away to present state. Wait, I just explained it all :P

Comment: @rijulgupta: it explains it perfectly well.  The cosmological horizon is not an edge of the universe.  The big bang is not an explosion whose shockwave is the cosmological horizon.  The things have close to nothing to do with each other.

Comment: Please read the question again @Jerry, this answer talks about only the big bang while the question is about how can we see so far as we seem to see

Comment: @rijulgupta: and the numbers given indicate the radius of the cosmological horizon, or as described in popular literature, "the visible universe".