# Rate of expansion of universe during big bang

Tags: cosmology, universe, space-expansion, big-bang, faster-than-light

We say big bang was the explosion not in the space but of the space itself that took place in a fraction of seconds. Speaking practically, we say the universe has no edge and is infinite. If the universe expanded to infinite in a fraction of seconds, can we say the rate of expansion during big bang (predicted) exceeded the speed of light?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/60519/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/26549/2451 and links therein.

Comment: [Note that the Big Bang didn't happen at a point](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/136860/did-the-big-bang-happen-at-a-point) and expand outwards like an explosion.