# Why is the radius of the universe larger than?

Tags: cosmology, universe, space-expansion, faster-than-light, observable-universe

It's always been in the back of my head that the Universe is 13.8~ billion years old and that the Observable Universe is 46~ billion light years in radius. How is this so? It would logically be only 13.8~ billion light years in diameter as that is the length of time it would take for things 13.8~ billion years to get to us?

Comment: Because [the universe is expanding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accelerating_expansion_of_the_universe). See answers to [related questions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space-expansion)

Comment: I would add that the expansion of the universe is accelerating.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is the observable universe so big?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/26549/)