# How can the universe expand faster than the speed of light?

Tags: cosmology, universe, space-expansion, big-bang, faster-than-light

In Neil deGrasse Tyson's *Astrophysics for People in a Hurry*, he writes:

> By now, one second of time has passed.
>
> *
>
> The universe has grown to a few light-years across...

If nothing can move faster than the speed of light, then it seems to follow that it should take a year after the big bang to reach a radius of one light-year.

This line of thinking brought me to another apparent paradox: the age of the universe is 13.8 billion years but it's radius is 46.6 billion light-years.

How is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/26549/2451 and links therein.

Comment: see also [Can space expand with unlimited speed?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/60519/84967).