# How big is the universe 1 second after the Big Bang?

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, big-bang, faster-than-light

In his book *Astrophysics for People in a Hurry*, Neil de Grass Tyson starts of with the Big Bang and narrates on what (probably) happened within the first moments of our universe. He further states (p. 26)

> By now, one second of time has passed. The universe has grown to a few light years across, about the distance from the Sun to its closest neighboring stars.

Q: Wouldn't this mean that by that means, the universe expanded vastly faster than the speed of light?

Comment: Also [Why is the observable universe so big?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/26549/why-is-the-observable-universe-so-big)

Comment: Tyson is being sloppy with language. Presumably he means the observable universe for a particular hypothetical observer.