# Matter moved faster than photons at big bang?

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, faster-than-light, observable-universe

The observable universe is 90 billion light years across. But the age of universe is 13.8 billion years. Light would take 90 billion years to cross this distance, how could matter move that far in only 13.8 billion years? Was it moving faster than light at the time of big bang?

Comment: Duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/26549/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is the observable universe so big?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/26549/)

Comment: Ok, thanks. I searched but couldn't find a duplicate so thought it was an original question. But now looking at the theory available on space expansion, I realize the question seems a bit trivial. However, it quickly gets complicated and seems more like hypothesizing, who knows the reality of the universe origins !

Comment: pretty much! The best we can do is operate on the basis of the best explanation for the evidence currently at hand. It is the orthodox interpretation of cosmology that the universe is expanding. Until we have reason not to believe this, i.e. maybe the universe has some nontrivial topology or something, we have not much better to work from