# Big Bang and relativity

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, space-expansion, big-bang, faster-than-light

Wasn't the big bang's explosion itself faster than speed of light? how does this not violate relativity, I had read an explanation earlier but it wasn't sufficient, can someone explain to me how the explosion itself is not faster than light

Comment: The spacetime itself streches faster than light, but that doesn't violate special relativity since there is no superluminal motion of matter. See [this](https://www.quora.com/How-was-the-Big-Bangs-expansion-faster-than-the-speed-of-light) question on Quora.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Did the Big Bang happen at a point?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/136860/)

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/60519/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/26549/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the big bang wasn't an "explosion". It just means that "at the start of the universe", if you want it to phrase like that, the spatial distance between every object was zero. It *doesn't* mean that the universe was shrunk to a single point. See [Did the Big Bang happen at a point?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/136860/) for more information.

But of course you are still right that space expanded faster than the speed of light. However, this is not a contradiction with (general) relativity. You can roughly think of it like that: Every object still moves with a velocity $<c$ relative to it's *local* frame of reference. It is only space(time) that moves faster than light, but GR allows this<sup>1</sup>. Some more information can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expansion_of_the_universe), especially [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expansion_of_the_universe#Metric_expansion_and_speed_of_light) section.

---

<sup>1</sup> You may have heard of the Alcubierre (warp) drive before which would theoretically work based on this.

Comment: so its just the space-time which expanded and not the matter itself

Comment: Essentially, yes (if you mean "and not the matter itself *moved*").